# 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable on django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I have been trying to recreate a social network but in the process I have found that there is one big error when a user logs out which is a TypeError `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable` I have tried different ways of doing this like using `if not request.user.is_authenticated():` or '@login_required' but nothing seems to work. I will like to make that if an unregistered user tries to see a page especifically the main view(home) the user should be redirected to the login page.

views.py

```
def home(request):
    following, created = Following.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user = Following.objects.get(user=request.user)
    followed_users = [i for i in user.followed.all()]
    followed_users.append(request.user)

    contents = Post.objects.filter(user__in = followed_users)

    context = {
        "contents": contents,
    }
    print("nice")
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

def profile(request, username=None):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        profile_bio = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)

    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        profile_bio = Profile.objetcs.filter(user=request.user)
        
    args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'profile_bio': profile_bio,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('<username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

If you have any questions or need to see more code please let me know;)

Comment: Can you add the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle requiring users to be logged in is by using a custom Middleware.

```
class RequireLoginMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if request.path != LOGIN_PATH and request.user.is_anonymous():
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return response
```

Comment: Hey! Is that all the code I need to add or I need to add some more code because I just added this and it returned the same error.